# How to merge object with list of the same object for list of such object?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have following classes:

```
        public class Animal
        {

        }

        public class Merge
        {
            public Animal First { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<Animal> All { get; set; }
        }
```

Is that possible if  i have a `List<Merge>` by means of Linq get list of `List<Animal>` which contains all the animal for each `Merge` object (both First and All)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you somethink like SelectMany ? https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Would be great if you could provide sample input/output of what you would like to achieve ?

Comment: with extension like `public static IEnumerable<T> WithFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> all, T first)
 {
  yield return first;
  foreach(var element in all)
   yield return element; 
 }` you can use [`var animals  = merges.SelectMany(m=>m.All.WithFirst(m.First));`](https://ideone.com/BOSu3f)

Answer (score 0):

```
        IEnumerable<Merge> merges = new List<Merge>();
        var animals = merges.SelectMany(m => m.All).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Animal
    {
             //some codes...
    }


public class Merge
    {
       public Merge()
        {
           AnimalFirst=new Animal();
        }
        public AnimalFirst { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Animal> All { get; set; }
    }

     List<Merge> merges = new List<Merge>();
     var animals = merges.AnimalFirst ;
     var All =merges.All;
     var AllAnimals = merges.SelectMany(m => m.All).ToList();
     var SelectAanimals = merges.Where(m => m.ID==1).FirstOrDefault();
```